# Is it possible to change Codeigniter set_flashdata to an array?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I would like to change codeigniter set_flashdata() function to become an array it is it possible ?

the normal function like that: `$this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'there is an error');`

I need to be like that `$this->session->set_flashdata(array('error'=>'there is an error'),'Description'=>'all fields required');`

If it possible how to echo it on view? and if not what you can suggest ? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

resolved:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('error', array('error'=>'lock', 'msg'=>'lock'));
```

view:

```
$ero=$this->session->userdata['error']['error'];
$msg=$this->session->userdata['error']['msg'];
```